# How to make faExternalLink icon smaller in superscript?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, superscripts, fontawesome5

I have the following LaTeX from [`fontawesome5`](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome5/):

```tex
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

% ...

Foo \textsuperscript{\faExternalLink*}
```

Here's how it looks: [image: screenshot of LaTeX rendering]

How can I make the superscript `\faExternalLink*` smaller, while still keeping it a superscript?

Comment: `\textsuperscript{\tiny\faExternalLink*}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can use any normal font size command:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

Foo \textsuperscript{\faExternalLink*}

Foo \textsuperscript{\tiny\faExternalLink*}

Foo \textsuperscript{\fontsize{2pt}{2pt}\selectfont\faExternalLink*}


\end{document}
```